# Laravel request file extension different then the submitted Blob

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I recorded an audio in my Chrome browser and that results in a Blob:
[image: Console response]

But when I submit this to my Laravel application like this:

```
$name = implode('.', [str_random(65), $request->file('audio')->extension()]);
Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs('files', $request->file('audio'), $name);
$mime = $request->file($file)->getMimeType();
```

The extension is: `.webm` instead of `.mp3`
And the mime type is `video/webm` instead of `audio/mp3`.

Comment: Which audio mime types are listed for the web server? Add `audio/mpga` if it isnt already included. `audio/mpeg` and `audio/mp3` should be there but worth checking those also.

Comment: Your laravel version??

Comment: Can you share browser-side code as because if you are sending `.mp3` file to your server then mime type will be `audio/mpeg` and if it is in `.webm`(same extension for both audio and video) then mime type will be `audio/webm` or` video/webm`. So, I think we need to check client-side code.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter what you mean? where? im on nginx.

Comment: @Davit latest, 5.6

Comment: @KevinPatel this package https://github.com/Lorti/vue-dictaphone, mime is video/webm what I'm receiving. but as seen in the screenshot it's "generated" as audio/mp3 blob

Comment: Nginx mime types can be found in `/etc/nginx/mime.types`. Check that the proper audio mimes are listed for mp3.

Comment: Here is a list with media types for reference: https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/mime.types

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I think they are? https://www.dropbox.com/s/xiclnwpvnek386h/Schermafdruk%202018-07-05%2019.36.40.png?dl=0

Comment: Try adding `audio/mpga      mp3;` to that list

Comment: Not working either @DigitalDrifter

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how the file is encoded, which is detected by the mime-type regardless of extension. If you actually want to convert the file to an mp3, you will need to use a codec for that. I believe [FFMpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) will work with webm files, plus there is a Laravel package for it: https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try [getClientOriginalExtension()](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientOriginalExtension) ?

> The `extension` method will attempt to guess the file's extension based on its contents. This extension may be different from the extension that was supplied by the client

`file()` returns an instance of [UploadedFile](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) which has a method `getClientOriginalExtension()`

> Returns the original file extension.
>
> It is extracted from the original file name that was uploaded. Then it should not be considered as a safe value.

Comment: That's not working. Still getting video/webm. It's laravel, there it's extension the same as  getClientOriginalExtension() by the way.

Comment: Try `dd($request->file('audio'))` and check if your browser is actually sending `audio/mp3` mime type.